# Control Ableton Live tempo from MaxMSP

Tags: midi, max-msp-jitter, ableton-live

My question is firstly- is midi cc information integer only? i.e. 0 - 127 but **not** 5.55

The reason I ask is that I'm trying to control the tempo in Ableton Live from MaxMSP.

I found out that midi-cc 0 registers a tempo of 20bpm, and midi-cc 127 registers a tempo of 999bpm

But it seems like my accuracy is totally ruined, because each cc integer is about 9bpm apart, and 9bpm off isn't very convincing. Too messy

I'm wondering if there is something I missed, or maybe another protocol to use. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1) midi sends only integers, so this is not a good way to control high-accuracy parameters such as bpm.

2) i would strongly recommend using OSC. Create a max for live patch that accesses Live's tempo with a live.object and use a udpreceive object to receive values you send with udpsend in max.

Let me know if this is clear enough, alternately i can craft you an example max for live patch.

Cheers

Comment: The only problem is here, I'm not working with Max for Live. But I have osculator so sending osc from max to live is no problem.

Comment: I see.. but how does osculator communicate with Live? If it uses midi than this defeats the purpose I'd say.

Comment: You're right, Osculator does use Midi. Eventually I found out that precise tempo control, in so far as Midi Mapping to Lives Tempo Parameter is significantly inaccurate, there are a few forum threads lamenting it. What I settled for (which is even worse but I enjoy the inaccuracy :-) was to constantly bang the Tap Tempo button from Max. The other alternative someone suggested was using the sync~ object, which is somehow able to produce it's own midi clock, but I had trouble syncing live to this. Hope these options help others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If you were using max for live you Would be able to use the Live Object Model to do what you want.   Use `live.path` and `live.object` to select the `live_set` object, and send the live.object the message `set tempo [val]`.  If you're doing lots with Max/MSP and live, it might be worth the cross-grade.

[image: Set Tempo of a live set]

Answer (score 0):

Yes MIDI is 7Bit so max number is 127 (0 to 127 = 128).
But you can use to CC to use 14Bit controller.

LSB MSB Controller

Here you can find a explanation:

https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/msb-lsb-applications/